# ConcurrentHashMap vs HashMap and NullPointerException

Tags: java, hashmap, concurrenthashmap

Currently I'm working with `ConcurrentHashMap` and I'm very familiar with `HashMap`,  I've expected a similar behaviour to `HashMap`, but when I insert a `null` key or value, `ConcurrentHashMap` throws a `NullPointerException`.

I saw their sources, the `ConcurrentHashMap`'s fragment:

```
...
public V put(K key, V value) {
    return putVal(key, value, false);
}
...
final V putVal(K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent) {
    if (key == null || value == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    ....
```

And the `HashMap`'s fragment:

```
...
public V put(K key, V value) {
    return putVal(hash(key), key, value, false, true);
}
...
final V putVal(int hash, K key, V value, boolean onlyIfAbsent, boolean evict) {
    Node<K,V>[] tab; Node<K,V> p; int n, i;
    // It Doesn't check null key or value.
    ....
```

Why are they so different when they are working with `null` keys or values? This doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html: `Like Hashtable but unlike HashMap, this class does not allow null to be used as a key or value.`

Answer (score 2):

You can refer Doug Lea comment:

The main reason that nulls aren't allowed in ConcurrentMaps (ConcurrentHashMaps, ConcurrentSkipListMaps) is that ambiguities that may be just barely tolerable in non-concurrent maps can't be accommodated. The main one is that if map.get(key) returns null, you can't detect whether the key explicitly maps to null vs the key isn't mapped. In a non-concurrent map, you can check this via  map.contains(key), but in a concurrent one, the map might have changed between calls.

Comment: I could understand this reason for the key, but for value??

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) you can see:

> This class and its views and iterators implement all of the optional
>   methods of the Map and Iterator interfaces.
>
> Like Hashtable but unlike HashMap, this class does not allow null to
>   be used as a key or value.
>
> This class is a member of the Java Collections Framework.